# Can there be more prophets after Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, prophets

In the name of Allah, the most merciful and the most gracious. May I be forgiven if I commit a sin even asking this question.

I read somewhere that there is a difference between Messengers (Rasuls) and Prophets (Nabis). A Messenger is apparently someone who receives new Sharia from Allah, and the Prophet is someone who can only guide his people to the ways of the previous Messenger. If so, can there be a new Prophet after Muhammad (PBUH)? Is there explicit mention of this issue in the Quran?

Again, I could be completely wrong, so please forgive me if I am.

Comment: The Prophet  (SAW) is called the seal of the prophets in the Quran: 33:40

Comment: This is relevant if not covering your issue [Why Muhammed is the last prophet and god doesn't send anyone else?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/why-muhammed-is-the-last-prophet-and-god-doesnt-send-anyone-else)

Comment: maybe duplicate of: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/is-muhammad-the-last-rasool-messenger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

> Verse (33:40)  Muhammad is not the father of [any] one of your men,
>   but [he is] the Messenger of Allah and last of the prophets. And ever
>   is Allah , of all things, Knowing.

What else you want to prove that prophet Muhammad S.A.W. is the last Messenger.

Allaho-Akber: see the ayah, it say, ... he is a RASOOL of Allah and seal to the Nabiyeen.

Comment: this answer lacks an important component: proof of that "seal of the " means "last".

Comment: Bro look the meaning of KHATAMA, if you can understand Arabic.

Comment: see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23408

Answer (score 1):

No, the Quran says:

> #### محمد ... رسول الله وخاتم النبيين
>
> Muhammad is ...  the Messenger of Allah and last of the prophets.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:40](http://quran.com/33/40)</sup>

In its tafsir the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ himself clearly stated:

> أنا خاتم النبيين لا نبي بعدي
>
> I am the last of the prophets, there is no prophet after me.
>
> <sup>— [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2219) , [Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4252)</sup>

The same statement that there is no prophet after him, has also occurred in other ahadith for example see in Bukhari ([3455](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3455), [4416](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4416), [3535](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3535)) and Muslim ([523](https://sunnah.com/muslim:523a), [2354](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2354)) etc.

Answer (score 0):

After Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) there shall be no prophet, as the Prophet was Seal of the Prophets. The Scholars agree that every Messenger is a Prophet, but not every Prophet is a messenger. Now, if the Messenger was Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) who was sent as the final Messenger, with Messenger being higher in status than Prophets, then it would be logical to assume that there would be no Prophet and Messenger sent after the Prophet (PBUH). This is supported by Tafsir Ibn Kathir, 33:40 and Sheikh Uthaymeen.

Every good I have mentioned is from Allah (SWT) and everything bad I mentioned is from me and I seek forgiveness for my shortcomings and mistakes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The title of the Seal of the Prophets has been given to the Prophet of Islam in the Holy Qur'an by God Almighty, so God Almighty is the first person to raise the issue of the Seal of the Prophet of Islam, the Holy Qur'an has called him the Seal of the Prophets. The idea that another prophet will come into the world after our Prophet is contrary to the belief in the prophethood of this Prophet. In addition to the text of the Holy Quran, even if it were not for the text of the Quran, there are other undeniable rational and narrative reasons for this. Therefore, the issue of Khatamiyyah is one of the necessities of the holy religion of Islam. (1)
In verse 40 of Surah Al-Ahzab, God Almighty has clearly called the Holy Prophet Muhammad Mustafa (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) the Seal of the Prophets.’’ Muhammad was not the father of any of your men, but the Messenger of God and the Seal of the Prophets’’.(2)

(1): Motahari, Mortada, Khatamit, vol. 1, p. 13.
(2): Ahzab / Surah 33, verse 40.

Answer (score -1):

NO their will be no neither any prophets after Muhammad,because Allah said that that is the last prophet in the world and Allah swear at prophet Muhammad S.A.W every time say S.A.W when you hear the name of all the prophets including MUHAMMAD S.A.W.

```
  Thank you
```

Answer (score -3):

There can be prophets after Muhammad saw, but not with a new teaching. Hadhrat Muhammad saw is the last prophet with teaching.

Guide us in the right path –  The path of those on whom Thou hast bestowed Thy blessings. (Ch.1:Vs.6-7)

Qur'an says 'And whoso obeys Allah and this Messenger of His shall be among those on whom Allah has bestowed His blessings, namely, the Prophets, the Truthful, the Martyrs and the Righteous.' (Ch.4:V.70)

There are also many hadith that prove this.

‘O ye people you should say that the Holy Prophet is Khataman Nabiyyeen, but do not say that there will be no prophet after him.’ (Durr e Manthoor, vol. 5, p.386).

Here the Holy Prophet(sa) is again referring to law-bearing prophets. This is clear from the full version of the hadith which states,

‘I am the last of the prophets and my mosque is the last mosque.’ (Sunan Nassai, vol. 2, p.35).

Last doesn't mean the final, it means that it is the greatest, the last that will be so great.